# Runtime exception while inflating using layoutInflator xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/theNewsTile"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/newsImage"
        android:src="@drawable/BackGround"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <TextView
            android:text="MbSoft News App"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:minWidth="220dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/link"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my axml file to be inflated saved in

> NewsTile.axml

file 
I am trying to inflate it using

```
RelativeLayout rl = this.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.newsContainer);
                    var viewObj = this.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.NewsTile,rl,false);
                    viewObj.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2).Text = rss.Title;
                    TextView tv = viewObj.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
                    Toast.MakeText(this, tv.Text, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    tv.Text = rss.Title;
                    rl.AddView(viewObj);
```

I am new to

> XAMARIN

and stocked.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in Advance.
This is the part of the debug which may be useful

> 08-21 22:16:15.219 D/Mono    (11091): Probing '__android_log_print'.
>   08-21 22:16:15.229 D/Mono    (11091): Found as '__android_log_print'.
>   08-21 22:16:15.259 I/MonoDroid(11091): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 08-21
>   22:16:15.369 I/MonoDroid(11091): Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Exception
>   of type 'Java.Lang.RuntimeException' was thrown. 08-21 22:16:15.369
>   I/MonoDroid(11091): at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
>   08-21 22:16:15.378 I/MonoDroid(11091): at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod
>   (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00064] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:195
>   08-21 22:16:15.389 I/MonoDroid(11091): at
>   Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate
>   (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup,bool) [0x00082] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:687
>   08-21 22:16:15.389 I/MonoDroid(11091): at
>   NewsApplication.MainActivity.GetFeedItems () [0x000c5] in
>   c:\Users\superfast\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\NewsApplication\NewsApplication\MainActivity.cs:62 08-21
>   22:16:15.409 I/MonoDroid(11091): at
>   NewsApplication.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00015] in
>   c:\Users\superfast\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\NewsApplication\NewsApplication\MainActivity.cs:33 08-21
>   22:16:15.409 I/MonoDroid(11091): at
>   Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2707
>   08-21 22:16:15.409 I/MonoDroid(11091): at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   object.9daf293e-e190-4f49-8a44-fd40442dd081 (intptr,intptr,intptr)  08-21 22:16:15.409 I/MonoDroid(11091):   --- End of
>   managed exception stack trace --- 08-21 22:16:15.409
>   I/MonoDroid(11091): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line
>
> ## 1: You must supply a layout_width attribute. 08-21 22:16:15.409 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
>   08-21 22:16:15.409 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5458)
>   08-21 22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:5594)
>   08-21 22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.(LinearLayout.java:1809)
>   08-21 22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1721)
>   08-21 22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
>   08-21 22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748) 08-21
>   22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 08-21
>   22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 08-21
>   22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 08-21
>   22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   md52a660c74cd716f3b9a164dea37c81895.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native
>   Method) 08-21 22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   md52a660c74cd716f3b9a164dea37c81895.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
>   08-21 22:16:15.419 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 08-21
>   22:16:15.429 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   08-21 22:16:15.429 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>   08-21 22:16:15.429 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>   08-21 22:16:15.429 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 08-21
>   22:16:15.429 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>   08-21 22:16:15.429 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-21 22:16:15.429
>   I/MonoDroid(11091):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-21
>   22:16:15.429 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 08-21
>   22:16:15.439 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-21
>   22:16:15.439 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 08-21 22:16:15.439
>   I/MonoDroid(11091):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   08-21 22:16:15.439 I/MonoDroid(11091):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 08-21
>   22:16:15.439 I/MonoDroid(11091):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-21 22:16:15.509
>   D/AndroidRuntime(11091): Shutting down VM 08-21 22:16:15.509
>   W/dalvikvm(11091): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40a13300) An unhandled exception occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element needs both an `android:layout_width` and an `android:layout_height` attribute. The last `TextView` in your layout lacks them.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine when **android:layout_width** and **android:layout_height** added to the 2nd **TextView**. Thank you. :)